# Cannot import Google Places PlacePicker into Android project

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm attempting to write a simple program that involves using a `PlacePicker` to capture location information.  My project, however, can't seem to resolve the necessary imports.

`build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
}
```

Activity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place; // "Place" is not resolved
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker; // "ui" is not resolved
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

The `LatLng` import seems to work, but not the other two.  The whole project runs fine when I import the full `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0` API, but I want to use specific API calls to cut back on unnecessary libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by "The whole project runs fine"? Aren't you importing the full maps package anyways?

Comment: @cricket_007 - Looks like my initial question has a misstatement.  I mean to say it only worked when I imported the complete Google play-services package (i.e. maps, location, auth, identity, fitness, etc), which is a huge excess of libraries I do not need.  I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In play-services `9.2.0` the `places` API is no longer located in `location`.  Those are now in their own `places` dependency.  To resolve those you should add this to your `build.gradle`.

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'`

It's been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075730/1352491)

Comment: It is great. Thanks.

Comment: This took far too long to figure out. I'm still curious, does it say this somewhere on the Google Places API 'Getting Started' page?