# Places class is removed from android play services 9.2.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

Today, I updated to google play services to 9.2.0. 
I got an error

> com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places

not found. that broke below two lines

```
.addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
.addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
```

any leads on where i can find GEO_DATA_API, PLACE_DETECTION_API

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In 9.0.2, the 'places' library was inside 'location' library. In 9.2, you need to add 'places' library as dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

Comment: FYI, this fixes the missing `LatLng` class too.

Answer (score 3):

The document is not updated as of 28th June. I suggest downgrading play services library to 9.0.2. (docs last updated on 23th June).

Edited:
as Emerson suggested,

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'

add that for places library to your Gradle. It's not updated in official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

for play service 9.2.0 places import has changed from

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places;
```

to

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
```

or you need all places folder

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.*;
```