# Selective Google Play Services API not finding classes

Tags: android, import, location, google-play-services

I've updated play services to the latest version, which currently is at **9.2.0** and I also want to use selective modules for the google play services.

```
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
```

The issue I'm having, is that now the imports like:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;

import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
```

Cannot be resolved anymore, although in their documentation it is stated that location services should provide Places features also.

Can someone help me with this Issue? Thank you.

Comment: Did you notice that we have `play-services-places` too ? seems like in 9.2.0 they splitted it

Comment: Have you built your project since adding the dependency?

Comment: @Selvin
I studied the list from this page: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project.

I didn't notice, I'm trying it now.

Comment: @Tanis.7x 
offcourse I did :)

Comment: @Selvin
You were right, they splitted the services. I gues the documentation wasn't updated.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Places class is removed from android play services 9.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068786/places-class-is-removed-from-android-play-services-9-2-0)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Based on the comment added by @Selvin, I managed to find the solution for my issue.

It seems that on version **9.x.x**, *Google Play Services API* for Places was moved from `play-services-location` into `play-services-places`.
Thus, now I'm having the following dependencies for *Google Play Services API*s:

```
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

Comment: You found a solution and you posted the answer for other people's benefit, thanks.